# Find the MGF of difference in Chi-Squared Random Variables: When is it legal to divide by an MGF?

Tags: probability-theory

Can someone please explain why the following two scenarios lead to different distributions?

1) $X\sim\chi^2(m)$ and $Y\sim\chi^2(n)$. Using moment-generating functions, show that $Y-X$ does not have a $\chi^2(n-m)$ distribution, for $n>m$ with $X$ and $Y$ independent.

Refer to the following for a derivation of this: [Distribution of Difference of Chi-squared Variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/transformation-of-difference-of-random-variables)

2) Show using MGF's that if $X\sim\chi^2(m)$ and $S = Y+X \sim\chi^2(n-m)$, then $S-X\sim\chi^2(n)$.

Here is my derivation:
$$
E[e^{(S-X)t}]=E[e^{St}]E[e^{-Xt}]\\
=\frac{M_S(t)}{M_X(t)}\\
= (1-2t)^{-(m+n)/2}(1-2t)^{m/2}\\
= (1-2t)^{-n/2}
$$
My question is: why can't we use this type of derivation (putting $M_X(t)$ in the denominator instead of using $M_X(-t)$) in (1)? Or alternatively, is there another way to show this using $M_X(-t)$ in the derivation?

Thanks!

Comment: What are you asked to prove in (2), exactly? The hypotheses are unclear, you might want to restate.

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is that you want $E[1/Z]$ to be  $1/E[Z]$ for a random variable $Z$ (in fact, when $Z > 0$ they are never equal unless $Z$ is almost surely constant).

Comment: Interesting... my professor definitely recommended this approach. Is there an alternative way to show (2)?

Answer (score 0):

there is another mistake that X and S are not independent, so the first equation is wrong.(E(XY)~=E(X)E(Y))