# Distribution of weighted difference of two $\chi^2_n$ random variables

Tags: probability-distributions

Let $X,Y \sim \chi^2_n$ be two independent $\chi^2$-distributed random variables with $n$ degrees of freedom. What is the CDF/PDF of
$$
Z = aX - b Y
$$
with $a>0, b>0$ ?

P.S. [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/distribution-of-difference-of-chi-squared-variables) answers the case $a=b=1$.

---

**My attempt**: Using the moment generating function (MGF), we can find
$$
\mathcal{M}_Z(t) = \mathbb{E}[e^{tZ}] = \mathbb{E}[e^{taX}e^{-tbY}] = \mathcal{M}_X(at) \mathcal{M}_Y(-bt)
$$
using independence, from which
$$
\mathcal{M}_Z(t) = \left[(1 - 2at)(1 + 2bt) \right]^{-\frac{n}{2}}
$$
Now, $\mathcal{M}_Z(-t) = \mathcal{L}_B[f_Z(z)]$, where $\mathcal{L}_B$ is bilateral Laplace transform and $f_Z(z)$ is the PDF of $Z$, so
$$
f_Z(z) = \mathcal{L}_B^{-1}[\mathcal{M}_Z(-t)] = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \left[(1 + 2at)(1 - 2bt) \right]^{-\frac{n}{2}} e^{-tz} dt
$$
How to proceed from here? Is this way any good? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: not sure if this will make a difference, but i think $$ \mathcal{M}_Z(t) = \left[(1 - 2at)(1 + 2bt) \right]^{-\frac{n}{2}} $$

Comment: @strider Thank you, fixed.